# Docker: unable to test a postgresql connection

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask

I'm following a Python/TDD/Docker tutorial by TestDriven.io.

I build a custom image and I want to test it. I cannot (I think, I'm a noob with Docker and Python, please patience) do.

This is the image: registry.gitlab.com/sineverba/warehouse:latest. It works because I deployed to Heroku with success.

I don't want docker-compose for testing the final image, so I tried to do:

```sh
docker network create -d bridge flask-tdd-net

export DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@flask-tdd-net:5432/users_dev

docker run -d --name app -e "PORT=8765" -p 5002:8765 --network=flask-tdd-net registry.gitlab.com/sineverba/warehouse:latest

docker run -d --name db -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=users_dev -p 5432:5432 --network=flask-tdd-net postgres:12-alpine
```

I can launch a simple

`docker exec app python -V` and get version, for example.

But when I launch

`docker exec app python -m pytest "project/tests"`

I get (split down, full log here: https://pastebin.com/tYjn65ys)

```sh
self = <[AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'") raised in repr()] SQLAlchemy object at 0x7fc74676e7f0>
app = <Flask 'project'>, sa_url = None, options = {}

    def apply_driver_hacks(self, app, sa_url, options):
        """This method is called before engine creation and used to inject
       driver specific hacks into the options.  The `options` parameter is
       a dictionary of keyword arguments that will then be used to call
       the :func:`sqlalchemy.create_engine` function.

       The default implementation provides some saner defaults for things
       like pool sizes for MySQL and sqlite.  Also it injects the setting of
       `SQLALCHEMY_NATIVE_UNICODE`.
       """
>       if sa_url.drivername.startswith('mysql'):
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drivername'
```

I did try also (after stopping and removing containers and recreating DBs)

`export DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users`

So, moving name from users_dev to users.

Full repo link: https://github.com/sineverba/flask-tdd-docker/tree/add-gitlab-warehouse

Thank you in advance!

### Edit

I changed the env cause link db was wrong. These are new commands, but got same error. I tried also to export both env, without success.

```sh
docker network create -d bridge flask-tdd-net
export DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users
docker run -d --name app -e "PORT=8765" -p 5002:8765 --network=flask-tdd-net registry.gitlab.com/sineverba/warehouse:latest
docker run -d --name db -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=users -p 5432:5432 --network=flask-tdd-net postgres:12-alpine

docker exec app python -m pytest "project/tests"


docker container stop app && docker container rm app && docker container stop db && docker container rm db
```

#### Starting example

This is the testdriven.io example, from Gitlab integration (that I want not use). Only env exported for app is the DATABASE_TEST_URL

```sh
image: docker:stable

stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  IMAGE: ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}

build:
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker build
        --cache-from $IMAGE:latest
        --tag $IMAGE:latest
        --file ./Dockerfile.prod
        "."
    - docker push $IMAGE:latest

test:
  stage: test
  image: $IMAGE:latest
  services:
    - postgres:latest
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: users
    POSTGRES_USER: runner
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: runner
    DATABASE_TEST_URL: postgres://runner:runner@postgres:5432/users
  script:
    - pytest "project/tests" -p no:warnings
    - flake8 project
    - black project --check
    - isort project/**/*.py --check-only
```

### Solved

The error is the need to export the variables inside the docker command:

`docker run -d --name app -e "PORT=8765" -p 5002:8765 -e "DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users" --network=flask-tdd-net registry.gitlab.com/sineverba/warehouse:latest`

Comment: You only have `DATABASE_TEST_URL` in your *local* environment. Also does you app use more than one env var to decide what database to connect to? I suspect you want `-e "DATABASE_URL=..."` when you run the app *in Docker*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe From starting example, only ENV VAR exported is that DATABASE_TEST_URL. I copied also the example start (taken from a Gitlab integrations). No other var to signal the dev env.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the need to export the variables inside the docker command:

`docker run -d --name app -e "PORT=8765" -p 5002:8765 -e "DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/users" --network=flask-tdd-net registry.gitlab.com/sineverba/warehouse:latest`